# If statement with String comparisson never runs?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test6
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int z = 0;
        while (z != 1)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
            Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
            String name = x.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\n"+"So your name is "+name+"?: ");
            Scanner y = new Scanner (System.in);
            String answer = y.nextLine();
            if ((answer == "yes")||(answer == "Yes"));
            {
                z = 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n"+"Great!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment The loop never ends? ;-) (Despite what else may occur, it will never, ever "normally" end in that code.)

Comment: @pst: Oh, I thought that a feature, deciding this guy just didn't enjoy dishing out flattery. ;)

Comment: This is a wall of code, not a question. In the future, please provide context beyond the title.

Comment: @Tim I agree with your general point but that's hardly a _wall_ of code. Perhaps a low ledge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), not `==`. There are [many questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20string%20equals%20operator) about this already.

```
if ("yes".equals(answer) || "Yes".equals(answer));
{
    z = 1;
}
```

In your case, [`String#equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) might more suitable:

```
if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(answer));
{
    z = 1;
}
```

---

Side note: you're using `z` like a boolean flag. Instead of using an `int`, **use a `boolean`.**

```
boolean z = true;
while (z)
{

}
```

Comment: But *why* does it matter? ;-) And why is "yes" first?

Comment: I generally prefer to compare with string literals on the left for null safety.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"yes".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)`.

Comment: @pst: [Yoda Conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined).

Comment: But are "Yoda conditions" relevant in Java since it is impossible to mistakenly use assignment when equality is intended (ignoring boolean assignment)?  Especially since we are using method calls, not operators...

Comment: same answer as @Matt Ball gave: for null safety reason.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a look at `String.equals()` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`, e.g. `answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")` or even `"yes".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use equals or in your case may be equalsIgnoreCase

```
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `equals("str")` on the String object will work.

```
if(answer.equals("yes") || answer.equals("no"))
{
   z = 1;
}
```

`==` compares references with strings, as `String` in Java is an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the concepts of [object identity and object equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Object_identity_vs._Content_equality).

In the Java programming language, the equals operator (`==`) tests if the left-hand and right-hand operands refer to the same exact object (aka referential equality, or object identity); however, the [`Object#equals(o)` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (which is overridden by the String class) tests if the calling object is "equivalent" to its argument.

Consider these examples:

```java
String s = "foo";
s == s; // => true, because the variable "s" obviously refers
// to the same object as itself.  They are "identical".
```

On the other hand:

```java
String a = new String("foo");
String b = new String("foo");
a == b; // => false, because there are two separate objects.
// However...
a.equals(b); // => true, because the strings have the same
// character sequences.  They are "equal".
```